# C# Iterate two list to no matchng / not containing with for loop only no linq

Tags: c#, foreach

I would like to add "john" and "Bryan" only to the list of NonExistList.

I have to loop thru `CollectionName` and if names are not in `ConfigName`, I would like to add them to the new list.

```
List<string> CollectionNames = new List<string>() { "Thomas", "Bryan", "John", "Mike" };    

List<string> ConfigNames = new List<string>() { "Thomas", "Mike" };

List<string> nonExist = new List<string>(); 

foreach (var nameC in CollectionNames)
{       
    foreach (var nameF in ConfigNames)
    {
        if(!nameC.Contains(nameF))
            nonExist.Add(nameC);
    }
}
```

Comment: `nameC.Contains(nameF)` not sure what you thing you are doing there, but `nameC` is a string at this point.

Comment: Please explain *why* you don't want to use LINQ. And given that you've also said this isn't really representative of what you're trying to achieve, please give more details of that as well...

Comment: You should just do `ConfigNames.Contains`, no need to loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without using anything from `System.Linq` (I assume this is some kind of exercise) you can do something like this:

```
foreach (var nameC in CollectionNames)
{
    bool isFound = false;
    foreach (var nameF in ConfigNames)
    {
        if (nameC == nameF) 
        {
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    } 
    if (!isFound) 
    {
        nonExist.Add(nameC);
    }
}
```

So the idea is, you loop through `CollectionNames`, and for each value (`nameC`) you check it against all the values in `ConfigNames`. If you find a match, you `break` out of the loop (you don't need to check the rest of `ConfigNames` once you've found your match). If you reach the end of the loop through `ConfigNames` without finding your item, you add it to `nonExist`.

Comment: Why not just `bool isFound = ConfigNames.Contains(nameF)`? (Or use LINQ, of course...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Because the OP seems pretty set on using loops. I assume it's some kind of programming exercise.

Comment: I don't think that's a given - I think it's more likely that the OP isn't aware of the alternatives.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't seen the "no linq" in the title before. I'd still use Contains to avoid an inner loop though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I would too. Or I'd just use Linq, because why not?

Comment: Hey John, Not all of us allowed to use linq where we develop for some reason, cobol architects

Comment: @RobertCohen: `Contains` isn't from LINQ, and if you can use it, you should in place of the inner loop.

Comment: ups gotta take that out as well then. Thanks all.

Comment: @RobertCohen: If you've got strange restrictions, you should explain what they are in the question, and the reasons behind them. Often WeirdRestrictionX often precludes PossibleSolutionY... or the reason behind WeirdRestrictionX is based on a misunderstanding, and after the misunderstanding has been resolved, the restriction is removed. Basically, it's in *everyone's* best interest to give that background.

Comment: @RobertCohen I would hate not being able to use LINQ, its the best!